# Gwt flex table getRowCount() method not returning current value

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

I am using a GWT`FlexTable` and have one issue: I am deleting any row after that when I do try to add new row it is giving `rowcount` value including removed row because of this
    while iterating last row giving 
    `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
for( count=0; count < table.getRowCount(); count++ )
{

}
```

Giving this exception

```
[FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
 [java] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
 [java] Column index: 0, Column size: 0
```

Comment: How do you remove the row?

Comment: using flextable.removeRow(int rowIndex) method

Comment: with the help of fireBug its displaying deleted row as <tr> </tr>

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at demo on [GWT Showcase - FlexTable](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFlexTable).

Here is the code to add/remove a row directly from show case. Use these method to perform these operation. Always check the row count first before doing any operation.

```
/**
 * Add a row to the flex table.
 */
private void addRow(FlexTable flexTable) {
    int numRows = flexTable.getRowCount();
    flexTable.setWidget(numRows, 0, widget1));
    flexTable.setWidget(numRows, 1, widget2));
    flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 1, numRows + 1);
}

/**
 * Remove a row from the flex table.
 */
private void removeRow(FlexTable flexTable) {
    int numRows = flexTable.getRowCount();
    if (numRows > 1) {
        flexTable.removeRow(numRows - 1);
        flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 1, numRows - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can your share a testable and minimal running code.

Comment: sorry i can not put images it needs 10 reputation..... it is happening when i do delete last row .i have checked with firebug it showing  empty tag <tr> </tr>

Answer (score 0):

if u using button to remove row.. write a click handler when remove a perticular row.

```
 Button removeSelectedRow = new Button();
 removeSelectedRow.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    int rowIndex = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
    flexTable.removeRow(rowIndex);
  }
});
```

Don't use rowCount().
use like this getRowIndex() position.
It will help to remove a row it can present in any order or any position or anywhere in your page. is this your need?

Comment: i am using rowCount to check name under name column  should not repeat ....getting exception at last Row iteration .

Comment: this might be work, 
     for (int count=flextable.getRowCount()-1; count>=0;count--){
                        flextable.removeRow(i);
                }
this will remove all rows from flex table.